# Prevent apps from changing the default app to open PDF files?

Tags: finder, applications, pdf, preview, adobe-photoshop

The Preview app used to be the default app to open PDF files. For some obscure reason, this is being changed into Photoshop every now and then.

If this happens, I do this:

- Right click on a PDF file, Open With...
- For some reason Preview isn't even in that list, so I click Other
- Select Preview, check the 'Always Open With' box, and click Open
- Then I right-click the file again, Get Info
- The "Open With" part shows Preview, and I click the "Change All" button

And then it's OK for a while. But a few days later, without me changing any settings, for some reason PDF files are being opened with Photoshop again :(

Is there a way to prevent an app from binding file types to itself without my permission?

FYI I'm using macOS High Sierra 10.13.2 (17C88).

Comment: Does this happen with other apps as well, or just with Preview?

Comment: @IconDaemon Just with Preview

Comment: any luck trying my answer?

Answer (score 1):

Try rebuilding your Launch Services database.

In Terminal:

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Frameworks/LaunchServices.framework/Support/lsregister -kill -r -domain local -domain system -domain user
```

Then reboot immediately.

References:

- https://www.tekrevue.com/tip/rebuild-launchservices-fix-duplicate-entries-os-xs-open-menu/
- https://eclecticlight.co/2017/08/11/launch-services-database-problems-correcting-and-rebuilding/

Comment: Thanks Matt, as soon as the situation occurs again, I will give this a try and let you know the results!